# what exactly is hypertext?

Tags: language-agnostic, html, languages, http

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext:

> Hypertext is text displayed on a computer or other electronic device
>   with references (hyperlinks) to other text that the reader can
>   immediately access, usually by a mouse click or keypress sequence.
>   Apart from running text, hypertext may contain tables, images and
>   other presentational devices. Hypertext is the underlying concept
>   defining the structure of the World Wide Web.[1] It is an easy-to-use
>   and flexible format to share information over the Internet.

So any webpage that does not have hyper links is NOT hypertext?

second question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_markup_language:

> HTML, which stands for HyperText Markup Language, is the predominant
>   markup language for web pages.

So HTML is not hypertext because it is not displayed on an electronic device, but HTML that is displayed on an electronic device like this:

```
<b></b>
```

is considered hypertext?

(I was debating whether to post this here or in English.StackExchange but thought probably here is a more appropriate channel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So any webpage that does not have hyper links is NOT hypertext?

Correct.  Trivially true and useless information.  But true.  No links means it's just text, not hypertext.

> So HTML is not hypertext because it is not displayed on an electronic device, but HTML that is displayed on an electronic device ... is considered hypertext?

You have successfully split a hair that did not need to be split.

This is also true and also useless.

This is the ever-so-subtle distinction between source code (HTML) and object code (displayed web page).

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is right in the wiki article you quoted. Let me quote it again:

> ... the word "hypertext" has become generally accepted for branching
>   and responding text ...

It's a very loose term, and I think it's safe to say that any text that can branch and response is hypertext (i.e. almost any text represented on an electronic device, nowadays).

HTML is simply a markup language to represent hypertext. It's not hypertext, itself. It allows a browser to render the hypertext.

Comment: Difference like between source and executable. HTML is source, markup, with "<a href=...". Hypertext is rendered text with actual clickable link.